How does fig.ncol work in for latex chunks?
This:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<,fig.show = "hold",out.width = "2cm",fig.ncol=2>>=
plot(1:100); plot(100:1); plot(1:100); plot(100:1); plot(1:100) 
@
\end{document}

Produces this:

It used to produce 3 rows of images, with 2,2 and 1 images in each row.
has something changed?
